# C# Error En Scriptcs

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes quiero correr este codigo pero al momento de correrlo me sale este error:

```
using System;

namespace SignificantFigures
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(SignificantFigures(3.14159265)); // Output: 9
            Console.WriteLine(SignificantFigures(0.00314159265)); // Output: 7
            Console.WriteLine(SignificantFigures(31415.9265)); // Output: 7
        }

        static int SignificantFigures(double number)
        {
            string numberString = number.ToString();
            // Eliminar los ceros a la derecha del punto decimal
            numberString = numberString.TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.');
            // Contar la cantidad de dígitos
            int sigFigs = numberString.Length;
            // Si el número es un entero, simplemente devuelve la cantidad de dígitos
            if (!numberString.Contains("."))
            {
                return sigFigs;
            }
            // Si el número es un decimal, devuelve la cantidad de dígitos después del punto decimal
            else
            {
                return sigFigs - (numberString.IndexOf(".") + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese es un error de Powershell. No encontró ningún archivo ejecutable llamado scriptcs ni un comando llamado así. Cómo lo estás compilando?

Comment: Prueba scriptcs.exe o .\scriptcs.exe en lugar de scriptcs